# Worklight 6.2: NativePage and iOS Storyboard

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, xcode-storyboard

Is it possible to use the iOS storyboard, containing NativePages and worklight webview?

I found this tutorial: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/integrating_a_worklight_based_ios_app_with_xcode_storyboard?lang=en

But I got issues trying to:

- Switch from NativePage to Storyboard ViewController
  (instatiateViewControllerWithIdentifier), and viceversa
- Switch from NativePage to WebView (NativePage
  showWebView:dictionary]))

Answer (score 0):

If by "NativePage" you are in fact referring to the `WL.NativePage` API, then the answer is no.

The `WL.NativePage` API does not offer the same amount of flexibility (= its position in the View Controllers hierarchy and the way it is managed) as the set of `SendAction` APIs (= where you create your own View Controller and manage it natively completely), and for this exact reason we opted to provide the "Integrating Xcode storyboard in Worklight apps" sample using SendAction.